# How to detect remote user shared screen from local user in agora rtc react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora-web-sdk-ng

I am using agora rtc react. By using it, I can share screens from the local end but can't detect it from the remote user end and vice versa.
Hooks i have used are,

````
import {
  ILocalAudioTrack,
  ILocalVideoTrack,
  LocalAudioTrack,
  LocalVideoTrack,
  RemoteUser,
  useJoin,
  useLocalCameraTrack,
  useLocalMicrophoneTrack,
  useLocalScreenTrack,
  usePublish,
  useRemoteUsers,
} from 'agora-rtc-react';```

All of them are working fine but I couldn't find any other way to detect screen share from other user end.
````